How can I disable UWP WebView2's drag and drop?
In my UWP application, I use a webview2 (from Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls).
And the web content shown inside of it can be drag-and-drop.
I want to disable this drag-and-drop feature, and I tried a lot of ways, but all failed.
E.g., AllowDrop="False" CanDrag="False"
How can I do it?
XAML code:
xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"

 <controls:WebView2 x:Name="_WebView2" Height="370" Width="792"
     NavigationStarting="WebView2_NavigationStarting"/>

C#:
await _WebView2.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();
_WebView2.CoreWebView2.Navigate(sourceStr);


"What" is being dragged, and "where", and why should it not do what it's doing?  It's tied to mouse moves and pointer presses and holding and "letting" things drop where allowed (i.e. intent). The "receiver" expects a certain data package; without it, there is no "drop" (regardless of what one can "drag").

The bounty attracted a ChatGPT (or similar) plagiariser.

Try this:
await _WebView2.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();
_WebView2.CoreWebView2.Controller.AllowExternalDrop = false;

It works in my test application.
You can see the documentation.

I get this: Error CS1061 'CoreWebView2' does not contain a definition for 'Controller'

what version are you using ?

The AllowExternalDrop property is at the top level of WebView2
_WebView2.AllowExternalDrop = false;

